# Slow down using Async calls with lock

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I was noticing an initial slow down in my process and upon taking multiple hangdumps, I was able to isolate the issue and reproduce the scenario using the following code. I am using a library that has locks and what not, which eventually calls the user side implementation of certain methods. These methods make async calls using httpclient. These async calls are made from within these locks inside the library.

Now, my theory as to what is happening (do correct me if I am wrong):
The tasks that get spun try to acquire the lock and hold on to the threads fast enough such that the first PingAsync method needs to wait for the default task scheduler to spin up a new thread for it to run on, which is 0.5 s based on the default .net scheduling algorithm. This is why I think I notice delays for total tasks greater than 32, which also increases linearly with increasing total tasks count.

The workaround:

1. Increase the minthreads count, which I think is treating the symptom and not the actual problem.
2. Another way is to have a limited concurrency to control the number of tasks fired. But these are tasks spun by a webserver for incoming httprequests and typically we will not have control over it (or will we?)

I understand that combining asyc and non-async is bad design and using sempahores' async calls would be a better way to go. Assuming I do not have control over this library, how does one go about mitigating this problem?

```
    const int ParallelCount = 16;
    const int TotalTasks = 33;

    static object _lockObj = new object();
    static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    static int count = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out int workerThreads, out int ioThreads);
        Console.WriteLine($"Min threads count. Worker: {workerThreads}. IoThreads: {ioThreads}");

        ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out workerThreads, out ioThreads);
        Console.WriteLine($"Max threads count. Worker: {workerThreads}. IoThreads: {ioThreads}");

        //var done = ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(1024, 1000);
        //ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out workerThreads, out ioThreads);
        //Console.WriteLine($"Set Max Threads success? {done}.");
        //Console.WriteLine($"Max threads count. Worker: {workerThreads}. IoThreads: {ioThreads}");

        //var done = ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1024, 1000);
        //ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out workerThreads, out ioThreads);
        //Console.WriteLine($"Set Min Threads success? {done}.");
        //Console.WriteLine($"Min threads count. Worker: {workerThreads}. IoThreads: {ioThreads}");

        var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < TotalTasks; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => LibraryMethod()));

            //while (tasks.Count > ParallelCount)
            //{
            //    var task = Task.WhenAny(tasks.ToArray()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            //    if (task.IsFaulted)
            //    {
            //        throw task.Exception;
            //    }

            //    tasks.Remove(task);
            //}
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        //while (tasks.Count > 0)
        //{
        //    var task = Task.WhenAny(tasks.ToArray()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        //    if (task.IsFaulted)
        //    {
        //        throw task.Exception;
        //    }

        //    tasks.Remove(task);

        //    Console.Write(".");
        //}

        Console.Write($"\nDone in {(DateTime.UtcNow-startTime).TotalMilliseconds}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Assuming this is the part where library methods are called,

```
    public static void LibraryMethod()
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            SimpleNonAsync();
        }
    }
```

Eventually, the user implementation of this method gets called which is async.

```
    public static void SimpleNonAsync()
    {
            //PingAsync().Result;
            //PingAsync().ConfigureAwaiter(false).Wait();
            PingAsync().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task PingAsync()
    {
        Console.Write($"{Interlocked.Increment(ref count)}.");

        await _httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            RequestUri = new Uri($@"http://127.0.0.1"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Get
        });
    }
```

Comment: Blocking on async calls defeats the entire purpose of async.

Comment: Yes. I understand that. Considering I do not have rights to modify this library, do you suggest using a non-async httpclient call (assuming there is one), which would affect performance since it is an io operation?

Comment: Note that [tasks are (still) not threads](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/)...

Comment: As soon as you take that lock `lock (_lockObj)`, you are no longer running in parallel and defeat the entire purpose of async.  Would it be possible to move that lock down to where it is actually needed - where vars need syncing and such?  Right now, even if you had 2 or 2000 threads, that lock won't allow any other thread to run until the wait is complete.  Either that, or try and do the lock related work just once and leave it up and running, then threads will make sense.

Comment: Or maybe @SLaks would prefer I used http://blog.slaks.net/2013-10-11/threads-vs-tasks/ ;)

Comment: Why are you even using `SendAsync` why not just call `Send` and get rid of all your headaches. If the library does not support async callbacks then you should not try to make your callbacks async and use the syncronous methods instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> These async calls are made from within these locks inside the library.

This is a design flaw. No one should call arbitrary code while under a lock.

That said, the locks have nothing to do with the problem you're seeing.

> I understand that combining asyc and non-async is bad design and using sempahores' async calls would be a better way to go. Assuming I do not have control over this library, how does one go about mitigating this problem?

The problem **is** that the library is forcing your code to be synchronous. This means one thread is being blocked for every download; there's no way around that as long as the library's callbacks are synchronous.

> Increase the minthreads count, which I think is treating the symptom and not the actual problem.

If you can't modify the library, then you *must* use one thread per request, and this becomes a viable workaround. You *have* to treat the symptom because you can't fix the problem (i.e., the library).

> Another way is to have a limited concurrency to control the number of tasks fired. But these are tasks spun by a webserver for incoming httprequests and typically we will not have control over it (or will we?)

No; the tasks causing problems are the ones you're spinning up yourself using `Task.Run`. The tasks on the server are completely independent; your code *can't* influence or even detect them.

If you want higher concurrency without waiting for thread injection, then you'll need to increase min threads, and you'll also probably need to increase `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`. You can then continue to use `Task.Run`, or (as I would prefer) `Parallel` or Parallel LINQ to do parallel processing. One nice aspect of `Parallel` / Parallel LINQ is that it has built-in support for throttling, if that is also desired.